# Web server in python in plainText

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to expose a text file with Python web server.
I get some python code to run a web server :

```
import http.server
import socketserver

port = 9500
address = ("", port)

handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(address, handler)
print(f"Serveur démarré sur le PORT {port}")
httpd.serve_forever()
```

It's working fine. but i would :

- Run a web sever exposing textplain content (and not Html content).
- Set manually the workpath and name of index file (default: index.html)
- keep Python server Code simple and light

I found some help on the web :

```
handler.extensions_map['Content-type'] = 'text/plain'
or
handler.send_header('Content-Type','text/plain')
```

But none os this proposition work.
Could you help me to build a simple python code to do this ?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script for Python 2 with using only built-in modules, just place the absolute path of the file which you want to be served `<INSERT_FILE>`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import BaseHTTPServer
from io import StringIO
import sys
import os

class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

        def send_head(self):
                # Place here the absolute path of the file
                with open("<INSERT_FILE>", "r") as f:

                        body = unicode("".join( f.readlines()))
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8")
                self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(body)))
                #self.send_header("Server", "SimpleHTTP/1.1 Python/2.7.5")
                self.end_headers()
                # text I/O binary, and raw I/O binary
                # initial value must be unicode or None
                return StringIO(body)

if __name__ == "__main__":

        
        HandlerClass = MyHandler
        ServerClass = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
        Protocol = "HTTP/1.1"

        server_address = ('', 5555)
        HandlerClass.protocol_version = Protocol
        httpd = ServerClass (server_address, HandlerClass)

        print("serving on port 5555")
        httpd.serve_forever()
```

For python3 (`SimpleHTTPServer` module has been merged into `http.server`), place absolute path `<INSERT_FILE>`:

```py
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
  

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        # place absolute path here
        f_served = open('<INSERT_FILE>','rb')
        f_content = f_served.read()
        f_served.close()
        self.wfile.write(f_content)


if __name__ == "__main__":

        httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 5555), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
        httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Great. It will be just perferct written in python3. Could you help ?

Comment: Updated, FYI this is not the best approach but merely a POC

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using aiohttp with its lowlevel server, which is described [here](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_lowlevel.html):

You can either return plain text, or you change the content type of your `web.Response` to `text/html` to send data that will be interpreted as html.

You can just replace the `"OK"` in the `text="OK"` with whatever plain text you wish. Or you replace it with the content of your `*.html` and change the content_type.

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web


async def handler(request):
    return web.Response(text="OK")


async def main():
    server = web.Server(handler)
    runner = web.ServerRunner(server)
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, 'localhost', 8080)
    await site.start()

    print("======= Serving on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ ======")

    # pause here for very long time by serving HTTP requests and
    # waiting for keyboard interruption
    await asyncio.sleep(100*3600)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
loop.close()
```